# Dbt incremental model inside macro

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Hi i don't know if the following is the best approach but is what i have for now (i'm new in dbt)

I have multiple models that compare tables (models) to make a track of differences that are in between (for example table 1 has 1000 rows, those 1000 rows has to be loaded in table 2, if not i recorded which rows were not loaded in a errors_log_table).

I have this already develop for the first process in which to steps in this process calculates this differences. After i would love to create a single macro used to load those rows that were not able to be loaded in this errors_log_table. I though in calling a macro in which i pass as a parameter the model that have the differences already calculated, something like this:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'ephemeral'
    )
}}

{% call statement('log_error') %}
    {{ log_error({{ ref('name_of_the_model_with_differences') }}) }}
{% endcall %}
```

log_error being the macro, which has the follow code:

```
{% macro log_error(table) %}
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental',
        unique_key = ['error', 'file', 'rejected_record'],
        incremental_strategy = 'merge',
        merge_exclude_columns = ['error', 'file', 'rejected_record']
    )
}}

WITH log_error_sel AS (
    SELECT 
       'data doesn't loaded' AS ERROR
        ,'current_timestamp =' || CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS FILE
        ,-1 AS LINE
        ,-1 AS CHARACTER
        ,-1 AS BYTE_OFFSET
        ,'' AS CATEGORY
        ,-1 AS CODE
        ,'-1' AS SQL_STATE
        ,'' AS COLUMN_NAME
        ,-1 AS ROW_NUMBER
        ,-1 AS ROW_START_LINE
        ,1 AS c2
    FROM 
        {% if is_incremental() %}
            {{ source('source_catalog','errors_log_table') }}
        {% endif %}
),
differences AS (
    SELECT 
        rows_with_differences
        ,1 AS c1
    FROM 
        {{ ref(table) }}
)
SELECT 
    l2.ERROR
    ,l2.FILE
    ,l2.LINE
    ,l2.CHARACTER
    ,l2.BYTE_OFFSET
    ,l2.CATEGORY
    ,l2.CODE
    ,l2.SQL_STATE
    ,l2.COLUMN_NAME
    ,l2.ROW_NUMBER
    ,l2.ROW_START_LINE
    ,l1.registros
FROM
    differences l1
LEFT JOIN
    log_error_sel l2
ON 
    l1.c1 = l2.c2
{% endmacro %}
```

Is this even possible? what would you do?

Thanks